# SQL Azure MVC3 Primary Key Violation Using INSTEAD OF trigger

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql, azure-sql-database

I have recently begun working on an MVC3 application with a SQL Server 2008R2 backend.  The application receives streaming data from a web query and then inserts the data into a table as and when new data is received.  The application can sometimes receive data that has already been inserted (the data being received includes a pre-generated primary key - this key has been generated before my application receives it) in the event of this i do not want to insert this into the table as it is already present.  I realise I could generate my own primary key, however I do not want any duplicate rows in the database.

The easiest solution I could think of was an INSTEAD OF trigger on the table that fires on each insert and then ignores the insert if the row already exists (my thinking was then that the MVC app did not then need to check to see whether the record already existed before it attempted the insert).

This was working fine, however when I ported it to SQL Azure, I now receive a primary key violation error every time the MVC attempts to insert a row that already exists - as if the trigger is not functioning.  If I connect to the SQL Azure instance in SSMS and try and do the insert using a key that already exists in the table I receive no error, so I know that the trigger is present and functioning.

In the MVC code I am using LINQ to SQL classes I generated from the database and the InsertOnSubmit method on those classes.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Or alternatively suggest a better solution for what I am trying to achieve (I am sure there is a probably a better way to do it in LINQ or something).  I am pretty new to Azure, LINQ and MVC so any suggestions welcome!

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: Trigger code is now below - as I said this is working fine when I run it on my local SQL DB - and if I try and do an insert using an already existing primary key on the Azure DB in management studio it works OK.  The error only happens from within the MVC app running against the Azure DB.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[IO_Trig_INS_User] ON [dbo].[STRM_User]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
--Check for existing user. If there is no duplicate, do an insert.
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT P.UserId
      FROM dbo.STRM_User P, inserted I
      WHERE P.UserId = I.UserId))
   INSERT INTO dbo.STRM_User
      SELECT *
      FROM inserted
END
GO
```

Comment: Could you show a trigger, please?

Comment: I'd start by removing that implicit join. Ugh. There is no excuse for writing them 20 years after they were replaced by something better. They are a Sql Anti pattern. http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1934356557/ref=kinw_rke_tl_1

Comment: If you're new, why are you using LINQ to SQL and not EF? You can get 1000x more help on EF v. L2S. -- Can't you turn on SQL profiling/tracing and see exactly what's going on? -- consider retagging - it's a pure SQL Azure question, MVC is irrelevant

Comment: Yes I have rewritten it as ANSI standard SQL although this does not make any difference to the problem encountered.  What makes you think this is a pure Azure question and not related to MVC? As I do not encounter the error when connecting directly to the Azure DB - I only receive the error when the method is called in the MVC app. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since the error only happens from the application, I would profile to see exactly what is being sent in. Perhaps what you think is going into the inserted table is not what is actually going in. If it sends a batch of two records which are the same but are not currently in the table, it could get this error.

Comment: I have done that - what is being sent is what is expected. The application works fine when running on SQL2008R2, it only errors when pointed at the Azure DB.